Using callback functions
I am following a tutorial series and there's a lesson about callback functions featuring a simple calculator. I am inept at programming, but I do understand pointers and functions.
The tutorial demonstrated a simple case with two functions accepting (int, int) and a function that accepts function pointers as arguments, but I decided to take my own spin on it and pass an array of double and two size_t variables (to mark the beginning and end of the array) as arguments to the addition and a subtraction functions.
I tried to pass three arguments to all functions and a function pointer to the "operation" function.
I expected the program to add or subtract all the numbers in an array depending on the choice the user makes.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double add(double[], size_t, size_t);
double subtract(double[], size_t, size_t);

int main()
{
    double numbers[] { 1.3, 2.0, 3.5};
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = std::size(numbers);
    double(*operation)(double(*), double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end); // a function pointer
    char choice = '0';  // a char variable for the choice of operation
    double result;  // result of the operation for the output

    std::cin >> choice; // input

    if(choice == '+')
    {
        result = operation(add, numbers, &start, &end); // passing the addition function as an argument to the operation function
    }
    if(choice == '-')
    {
        result = operation(subtract, numbers, &start, &end);
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;   // output
}

double add(double numbers[], size_t *start, size_t *end)    // add all numbers in the array
{
    double result = 0;

    for(int i = *start; i < *end; i++)
    {
        result += numbers[i];
    }
    return result;
}

double subtract(double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end) // subtract the following numbers from the first one in the array
{
    double result = 0;

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        result -= numbers[i];
    }
    return result;
}

double operation(double(*op)(double, size_t, size_t), double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end)
{
    return op(numbers, start, end); // the function that accepts two functions as arguments
}

The error I get from the compiler is:
funcpointerscalc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
funcpointerscalc.cpp:20:28: error: cannot convert ‘double (*)(double*, size_t, size_t)’ {aka ‘double (*)(double*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)’} to ‘double*’ in argument passing
   20 |         result = operation(add, numbers, &start, &end);
      |                            ^~~
      |                            |
      |                            double (*)(double*, size_t, size_t) {aka double (*)(double*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)}
funcpointerscalc.cpp:24:28: error: cannot convert ‘double (*)(double*, size_t, size_t)’ {aka ‘double (*)(double*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)’} to ‘double*’ in argument passing
   24 |         result = operation(subtract, numbers, &start, &end);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            double (*)(double*, size_t, size_t) {aka double (*)(double*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)}
funcpointerscalc.cpp: In function ‘double* add(double*, size_t*, size_t*)’:
funcpointerscalc.cpp:37:12: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
   37 |     return *result;
      |            ^~~~~~~
funcpointerscalc.cpp: At global scope:
funcpointerscalc.cpp:40:9: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘double* subtract(double*, size_t, size_t)’
   40 | double* subtract(double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end)
      |         ^~~~~~~~
funcpointerscalc.cpp:5:8: note: old declaration ‘double subtract(double*, size_t, size_t)’
    5 | double subtract(double[], size_t, size_t);
      |        ^~~~~~~~
funcpointerscalc.cpp: In function ‘double* subtract(double*, size_t, size_t)’:
funcpointerscalc.cpp:48:12: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
   48 |     return *result;
      |            ^~~~~~~
funcpointerscalc.cpp: In function ‘double operation(double (*)(double, size_t, size_t), double*, size_t, size_t)’:
funcpointerscalc.cpp:53:15: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in argument passing
   53 |     return op(numbers, start, end);
      |               ^~~~~~~
      |               |
      |               double*



Whatever tutorial you're following, stop using it. It is not teaching you C++ as it should be used nowadays. double add(double[], size_t, size_t); should be double add(std::span<double>) (No "C" style array passing please). And for operations use std::function<double (std::span<double>)> instead of function pointers.  (You can benefit a lot from the fact you can then use lambda expressions for your operations).

you declare a function pointer and a function, both of the name operation and then you confuse the two. You arent using the function pointer so I suggest to remove it from the code for now

You have contradictory (or overloaded, depending on how you look at it) declarations of add. Does this function take two size_t parameters or two size_t * parameters? Make up your mind.

What tutorial series is it? Because I think the author should watch this CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C" and read the C++ core guidelines

Using std::function has simpler syntax than pointer on function and std::array/std::span might help too: std::function<double(double*, std::size_t, std::size_t)> op = add; double result = op(numbers, start, end);

Recommendation: Write less code at a time. Write a few lines, just enough to perform one easily testable task, then compile and test. Do not proceed until you have resolved all compiler errors and warnings and the results of all of the tests are as expected. If you build on a shaky foundation you will find A) you have multiple mistakes and need to waste time untangling them before you can fix them, B) you will repeat mistakes you could have caught early and solved once, and C) you'll have to throw out and rewrite code that can no longer perform as expected after repairing earlier mistake.

The other answer (by @463035818_is_not_an_ai) already explains the reason for your compilation errors and how to fix them.
In this answer I attempt to offer an alternative way (better IMHO) to implement the same functionality using more modern C++ mechanisms:

Use std::function instead of a function pointer for the callback.
std::function is more general and powerful representation of a callable.
Use std::span instead of a raw array with start and end markers.
This is exactly what a std::span is for - a lightweight abstraction of a continous range of elements.
Use a ranged-based for-loop instead of one with a manual index.

#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <functional>

double add(std::span<double> numbers) {
    double result{ 0 };
    for (auto num : numbers) result += num;
    return result;
}

double subtract(std::span<double> numbers) {
    double result{ 0 };
    for (auto num : numbers) result -= num;
    return result;
}

double operation(std::function<double(std::span<double> op)> op, std::span<double> numbers) {
    return op(numbers); 
}

int main() {
    double numbers[]{ 1.3, 2.0, 3.5 };
    std::cout << "add: " <<      operation(add,      std::span<double>(numbers)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "subtract: " << operation(subtract, std::span<double>(numbers)) << "\n";
}

Output:
add: 6.8
subtract: -6.8

Live demo

I can understand this solution, thank you!

@MarvelousMishap Great, happy to help !

There are some issues in your code.
Here
double(*operation)(double(*), double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end); // a function pointer

you declare a function pointer named operation. This gets into the way of calling the function called operation. The error you get now complains about add not being a double*, because that's how operation is declared: a function pointer whose first parameter is a double*.
Remove the declaration of the function pointer. You will now see that you attempt to call the function before it is declared: https://godbolt.org/z/n1WfW75Pc
Declare the function upfront like you did it for add and subtract. You will now see an error because the function point has the wrong signature:
double operation(double(*op)(double, size_t, size_t), double numbers[], size_t start, size_t end)

This function expects as first parameter a function pointer to function with double as first argument. Your add and subtract have double*.
Next, one of your functions takes start and end as pointers the other by value. That's not going to work. Stick with one. I will pass them by value, hence:
Wrong:
result = operation(add, numbers, &start, &end);

Correct:
result = operation(add, numbers, start, end);

And adjust the function signatures accordingly.
This is what makes your code compile: https://godbolt.org/z/aT7ravM9P. It is syntactically correct. You should now write tests to see if it does what it is supposed to do. For tests do not rely on std::cin. It's too inconvenient for frequent testing and you want reproducible runs. Write examples in the code where you can directly compare expected and actual outcome.

After you fixed your code you should take a look at std::function. If the tutorial is not mentioning it, the tutorial is not worth what you paid for it.

Thank you for a very detailed answer, now I understand

Your code in current C++ would look more like this :
#include <span>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <unordered_map>

[[nodiscard]] double add(std::span<double> numbers)    // add all numbers in the array
{
    return std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0); // if you can avoid loops altogether
}

[[nodiscard]] double subtract(std::span<double> numbers) // subtract the following numbers from the first one in the array
{
    double result = 0;
    for (const auto value : numbers) // if you cannot avoid a loop, use a range based for loop
    {
        result -= value;
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    // Create a map from tokens to functions and use std::function for this.
    // more flexible
    std::unordered_map<char, std::function<double(std::span<double>)>> operations
    {
        {'+',add},
        {'-',subtract},
        {'*', [](std::span<double> values){ double result = 1.0; for(const auto value : values){ result *= value; }; return result; }} // lambda expression
    };

    // or use function pointers
    using operation_function_ptr = double(*)(std::span<double>);
    std::unordered_map<char, operation_function_ptr> operation_ptrs
        {
        {'+',add},
        {'-',subtract}
    };

    std::vector<double> numbers{ 1.3, 2.0, 3.5 };

    char choice = '-';  // a char variable for the choice of operation

    //std::cin >> choice; // input

    if (operation_ptrs.contains(choice))
    {
        auto operation = operation_ptrs.at(choice); // select the correct function from the map
        auto  result = operation(numbers); // and call it
        std::cout << result << "\n";   // output    
    }
}

